# how to create route group in laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I have writing site with laravel with admin panel and UI,
how to create `route` in laravel like voyager in below code:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    **Voyager::routes();**
});
```

I mean the way Voyager is defined
What is this concept? What is it about?

Answer (score 0):

Check out docs for [Route Groups](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-groups)

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('users', function () {
        // Matches The "/admin/users" URL
    });
});
```